# Devolver la posicion donde se encuentre un numero en un array

Tags: java, array

Tengo el siguiente problema:

*/* 39 Desarrolla un método que reciba un array y un número entero. Nos debe devolver la
primera posición del array donde encuentre el número. Si no lo encuentra devolver -1.*/*

**Aquí envío el Array y el numero:**

```
int posicion;
int numero=4;
int[] array={2,3,4,5,6};
posicion=ej.ejercicio39(array, numero);
  System.out.println("La posicion es: "+posicion);
```

---

**Y Aquí hago el metodo:**

```
public int ejercicio39 (int[] array, int numero){

int i=0;
while(i<array.length){
    
    if(array[i]==numero){
        i=numero;
    }else {
        numero=-1;
    }
    i++;
}
return numero;
```

}

El problema es que me devuelve -1, Alguien me puede ayudar?? PD: Soy nuevo en la programacion.
Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás agotando el bucle en todos los casos. Debes poner un `return` cuando el  `if`  se cumpla simplemente. No necesitas `else` tampoco, sino retornar `-1` si el bucle se agota, lo cual significaría que no encontró el primer `return`.

El método podría escribirse así:

```
public int ejercicio39 (int[] array, int numero){
    int i=0;
    while(i<array.length){
        if(array[i]==numero){
            /*
               Si la condición se cumple retornas el índice
               al hacer return el bucle se detiene
            */
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    /*
       El código sólo entrará aquí cuando no haya encontrado
       un indice que sea igual a numero
    */
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: No sabía que se podía hacer de esa forma. Es mucho mas eficiente tu codigo!! a qué te refieres en que agoto el bucle?? un saludo!

Comment: @PabloFC en tu código original, al no poner un `return` dentro del `if`, agotabas el bucle (el bucle seguía iterando) y por ese motivo te mandaba `-1` por el valor se re-asignaba a  la variable `numero`